# Export Data in Excel from DB using .Net MVC and Date Range filter

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am in process to create a simple ticketing tool. I am working on a function where I could export data from DB applying Date Range format.

With the code I created, only the Rows are getting exported but not the View Result. Please take a look at the below code and help fixing this.

1. AllTickets View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "Ticket", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="datetime" name="start" id="start" />
    <input type="datetime" name="end" id="end" />
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

2. Filter Controller to show data between 2 dates

```
public ActionResult Filter(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                //Ticket dto = db.Tickets.Where(x => x.EscalatedOn >= start && x.EscalatedOn <= end).FirstOrDefault();

                var filterTicker = db.Tickets
            .Where(x => x.EscalatedOn >= start && x.EscalatedOn <= end).ToList();


                return View(filterTicker);
            }

        }
```

3. Code to download and export data

```
public FileContentResult Download(Ticket model)
        {
            //Ticket model = new Ticket();

            var fileDownloadName = String.Format("FileName.xlsx");
            const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";


            // Pass your ef data to method
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                var start = model.EscalatedOn;
                var end = model.EscalatedOn;

                ExcelPackage package = GenerateExcelFile(db.Tickets.Where(x => x.EscalatedOn >= start && x.EscalatedOn <= end).ToList());


                var fsr = new FileContentResult(package.GetAsByteArray(), contentType);
                fsr.FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;

                return fsr;
            }
        }

        private static ExcelPackage GenerateExcelFile(IEnumerable<Ticket> datasource)
        {

            ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();

            //Create the worksheet 
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");

            // Sets Headers
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Record Number";
            ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Reviewer";
            ws.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Resource";
            ws.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Ticket Number";
            ws.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Scenario";
            ws.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Status";
            //ws.Cells[1, 7].Value = "Escalated";
            ws.Cells[1, 7].Value = "SLA Status";
            ws.Cells[1, 8].Value = "Escalated On";
            ws.Cells[1, 9].Value = "Was This Legit Esc";
            ws.Cells[1, 10].Value = "Escalation Reason";
            ws.Cells[1, 11].Value = "Can we de-escalate in future?";
            ws.Cells[1, 12].Value = "How can we de-escalate?";
            ws.Cells[1, 13].Value = "Username";

            // Inserts Data
            for (int i = 0; i < datasource.Count(); i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).RecNo;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Reviewer;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Resource;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Number;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Scenario;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 6].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Status;
                //ws.Cells[i + 2, 7].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Escalated;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 7].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).SLAStatus;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 8].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).EscalatedOn;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 9].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).WasThisLegitEsc;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 10].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).EscalationReason;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 11].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).DeEscalate;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 12].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).HowCanWeDeEscalate;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 13].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Username;
            }

            // Format Header of Table
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:M1"])
            {

                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid; //Set Pattern for the background to Solid 
                rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Gold); //Set color to DarkGray 
                rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Black);
            }
            return pck;
        }
```

4. Filter View

```
@model IEnumerable<TicketTool.Models.VM.Ticket>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Filter";
}

<h2>Filter</h2>

<a href="@Url.Action("Download","Ticket")" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Export</a>

<table class="table">
    <tr><th>
        Ticket Number
        </th>
    <th>
        Escalated On
    </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EscalatedOn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CaseId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CaseId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CaseId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Any help on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Filter Action use `ViewBag`

```
public ActionResult Filter(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        using (Db db = new Db())
        {

            var filterTicker = db.Tickets
        .Where(x => x.EscalatedOn >= start && x.EscalatedOn <= end).ToList();


            ViewBag.START = start;
            ViewBag.END = end;
            return View(filterTicker);
        }

    }
```

then in Filter View

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Download", "Ticket",new {start = ViewBag.START , end = ViewBag.END })" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Export</a>
```

and finally in Download Action

```
public FileContentResult Download(Ticket model,DateTime start, DateTime end)
```

Comment: Thank you but, adding ViewBag.START; ViewBag.END; shows squiggle lines, which cannot get rid off. Anything I am missing on.

Comment: try `@ViewBag.START`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and help. very much appreciated. Here is what worked for me, very much your input helped me to complete the code. Save start and end in Global Variables like var st = start; var en - end; and further stored them in ViewBag.START = st; ViewBag.END = en. And then it did wonders for me. I will submit my code here for others to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me

1. All tickets View

```
{
    <input type="datetime" name="start" id="start" />
    <input type="datetime" name="end" id="end" />
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

2. Filter Controller to show data between 2 dates

```
 public ActionResult Filter(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            var st = start;
            var en = end;

            using (Db db = new Db())
            {

                var filterTicket = db.Tickets
            .Where(x => x.EscalatedOn >= start && x.EscalatedOn <= end).ToList();

                ViewBag.START = st;
                ViewBag.END = en;

                return View(filterTicket);
            }

        }
```

3)Code to download and export data

```
public FileContentResult Download(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {

            var fileDownloadName = String.Format("FileName.xlsx");
            const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";


            // Pass your ef data to method


            ExcelPackage package = GenerateExcelFile(db.Tickets.Where(x => x.EscalatedOn >= start && x.EscalatedOn <= end).ToList());


            var fsr = new FileContentResult(package.GetAsByteArray(), contentType);
                fsr.FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;

                return fsr;
            
        }

        private static ExcelPackage GenerateExcelFile(IEnumerable<Ticket> datasource)
        {

            ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();

            //Create the worksheet 
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");

            // Sets Headers
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Record Number";
            ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Reviewer";
            ws.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Resource";
            ws.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Ticket Number";
            ws.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Scenario";
            ws.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Status";
            //ws.Cells[1, 7].Value = "Escalated";
            ws.Cells[1, 7].Value = "SLA Status";
            ws.Cells[1, 8].Value = "Escalated On";
            ws.Cells[1, 9].Value = "Was This Legit Esc";
            ws.Cells[1, 10].Value = "Escalation Reason";
            ws.Cells[1, 11].Value = "Can we de-escalate in future?";
            ws.Cells[1, 12].Value = "How can we de-escalate?";
            ws.Cells[1, 13].Value = "Username";

            // Inserts Data
            for (int i = 0; i < datasource.Count(); i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).RecNo;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Reviewer;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Resource;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Number;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Scenario;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 6].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Status;
                //ws.Cells[i + 2, 7].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Escalated;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 7].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).SLAStatus;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 8].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).EscalatedOn;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 9].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).WasThisLegitEsc;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 10].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).EscalationReason;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 11].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).DeEscalate;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 12].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).HowCanWeDeEscalate;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 13].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Username;
            }

            // Format Header of Table
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:M1"])
            {

                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid; //Set Pattern for the background to Solid 
                rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Gold); //Set color to DarkGray 
                rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Black);
            }
            return pck;
        }
```

Then in Filter View

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Download", "Ticket",new {start = ViewBag.START , end = ViewBag.END })" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Export</a>
```

This worked great for me